# bizarre 500 errors from asana create task api

Tags: asana, asana-api

I'm trying to create a new task using the node.js asana library and I'm getting weird 500 errors:

500 error

```
{
  message:"Server Error"
  phrase: "29 bizarre cobras wait hourly"
}
```

create code

```
var task = {
  name: card.name,
  notes: card.desc,
  memberships:  [ { project: { id: someId, name: 'Discovery' }, section: section }],
  parent:null,
  workspace: workspaceId
};

client.tasks.create(task).then((results) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(task));
}).catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [error code documentation](https://asana.com/developers/documentation/getting-started/errors), "In the event of a server error the response body will contain an error phrase. These phrases are automatically generated using the node-asana-pharse library and can be used by Asana support to quickly look up the incident that caused the server error."

In this case the error is generated due to a poorly formed `memberships` parameter in the POST payload. Object references as parameters in the API only include the ID for the object instead of an actual object.

- Correct: `project: 123`
- Incorrect: `project: { id: 123, name: 'Discovery' }`

Therefore, the memberships parameter should be

- `memberships:  [ { project: 123, section: "A Section" }]`